# Xbox One Wireless Controller with USB Adapter - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and purchased the Xbox One Wireless Controller with USB adapter with the idea of using my old desktop computer for old-school Nintendo games for the kids via the FCEUX NES Emulator.

For starters, has anyone been able to sync the USB adapter and the Xbox One Wireless controller on 16.04 (or earlier)? I was able to get it to work on my Windows 10 desktop.

Answer (score 4):

Not yet. The problem is, the Wireless Adapter is-- in principle-- just a WiFi dongle based on the MediaTek MT7612U chipset. A piece of software is needed that translates network packets into gamepad inputs in a standardized way so they can be processed by any application or game. So the answer is: you will not be able to get it to work right now, but eventually, given some time, it'll work.

For more information, see:

- https://github.com/paroj/xpad/issues/14
- https://github.com/bytewarrior/xbox-one-wireless-adapter