# Bluetooth joypad paired but not connected

Tags: drivers, 16.04, bluetooth

I have one of the new Xbox One controllers with Bluetooth, and I am trying to pair it with my HTPC which is running Ubuntu 16.04 - I found [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/4w2i4z/a%E2%80%A6) which showed me it is possible.

When using the GUI, it appears to pair fine. However, the "connection" button on the device's page is greyed out and cannot be clicked.

Looking at the command line when pairing shows that it connects but then immediately disconnects.

```
luke@luke-HTPC:~$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 6C:71:D9:9A:81:62 luke-HTPC [default]
[bluetooth]# devices
[CHG] Controller 6C:71:D9:9A:81:62 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 46:F0:0F:7F:E5:F0 46-F0-0F-7F-E5-F0
[NEW] Device 42:CA:06:51:5F:67 42-CA-06-51-5F-67
[NEW] Device 5F:26:BA:C4:60:E6 5F-26-BA-C4-60-E6
[NEW] Device 42:90:38:C4:36:3B 42-90-38-C4-36-3B
[NEW] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Xbox Wireless Controller 7EED8021EC2F
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 42:90:38:C4:36:3B RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 5F:26:BA:C4:60:E6 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 42:CA:06:51:5F:67 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 46:F0:0F:7F:E5:F0 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Controller 6C:71:D9:9A:81:62 Discovering: no
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Trusted: yes
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Connected: no
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 
Attempting to connect to C8:3F:26:20:B5:42
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device C8:3F:26:20:B5:42 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

I don't use bluetooth all that often, especially not with Linux, and so I am unfamiliar with how it works. Is there anything here that points to what the problem is? Is it a driver issue? Should I update the bluetooth drivers? I have bluetooth 4.0 built into an ASUS P8-Z77-I motherboard. I can't find any Linux drivers for it.

Comment: I have the same problem on my laptop with that controller on archlinux with the latest 4.8.13 kernel and a bcm20702b0 dongle... but on a ShieldTV it pairs fine. Another controller (8bitdo) pairs fine with my laptop dongle, but won't pair on multiple other systems. No idea why.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/a/764434/219144

Comment: +1 for mentioning `bluetoothctl` to produce a report of what the device actually does